# How to call the function inside the plugin itself correctly

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

How can I call the function inside the plugin itself correctly? For instance, it works ok if I call the function like this,

```
init_tinymce();
```

But I will get an error that says `$.fn.get_tinyMCE.init_tinymce is not a function` if I call the function like this,

```
$.fn.get_tinymce.init_tinymce();
```

Below are the simplified code,

```
(function($){ 
   $.fn.extend({         
       get_tinymce: function () {
            var $cm = this.ready(function(e){
                if (tinyMCE.activeEditor != null || tinyMCE.activeEditor != undefined) {
                    //console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor);
                    for (var i = 0; i < tinyMCE.editors.length; i++) {
                        tinyMCE.remove(tinyMCE.editors[i]);
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //load_mce_basic();
                    }, 1000);
                } 
                else {
                    $.fn.get_tinymce.init_tinymce();
                    //init_tinymce();
                }           
            });         

            function init_tinymce(){ 
                alert('2');
            };

            $.fn.get_tinymce.init_tinymce = function() {
                alert('1');
            };
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.fn` extends the jQuery plugin library. If you add a function to the `$.fn` object like `$.fn.foo = function()`, you can call it like `$(elem).foo();`, where the `this` object refers to the DOM object of the `elem`.

More information: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

On your function, you can use it like:

```
$("textarea").get_tinymce();
```

Comment: yea thanks. but I still don't understand why can't I call the function inside the plugin itself like `$.fn.get_tinymce.init_tinymce()` - any ideas? thanks.

Comment: The `get_tinemce` is an object, see the `init_tinymce` as a private function of a class, which you wan't to call, that's not possible. If you see the Authoring page from jQuery, you can see how you can call functions from outside the object. Passing the method name as a string, and the plugin will find out which function to call. See the `events` part of the page.